# Does Deactivating a Plugin Help Anything?

Tags: plugins, deactivated-plugin

Does deactivating a plugin help with any performance on your website? I mean is it worth deactivating plugins that you don't use constantly? Does uninstalling a plugin make any difference from deactivating a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

The overhead of a plugin sitting in your plugin folder is negligible, and would have an impact on the plugins page. The main area of optimisation here is the % of free space on your filesystem.

Active plugins on the other hand can run queries, make remote requests, do expensive parsing, filesystem operations, and all manner of expensive, longwinded, slow operations.

Not all plugins are expensive to run however. Hello Dolly is a simple plugin that does almost nothing, whereas a plugin that fetches RSS feeds and creates posts can be an expensive plugin when you give it a lot of feeds.

If a plugin is expensive to run, deactivating it fixes that. A deactivated plugin is just a file sitting on the filesystem, not being executed.

Is it worth getting rid of plugins you aren't using? So long as they're kept up to date, there's no reason to remove them, but I would recommend keeping the plugins installed to those you actively use as not all plugins are maintained

Answer (score 0):

There is some overhead in that Wordpress parses all the files in the plugins folder at the top level.  It is looking for the comment section at the top of the file that contains the plugin info.  So the less files that are in this 'Plugins Folder' the better. Less parsing = faster.

I don't think deactivating it will help as much as deleting the files.

Comment: Time spent parsing PHP is tiny compared to the cost of a single database query, a basic shortcode, or a remote request

Comment: Tom is absolutely correct. If you are not using the plugin deactivate it for sure.  But why keep it at all if you are not using it?  Delete it too. Unless you paid good money for it. :-)